# Preparing dataset for Multivariate Time Series with LSTM in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm trying to solve time series prediction problem for multisequences data in Python using LSTM approach.

Following this manual, having some confusion [site here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)

In this manual, author solving problem for time series air pollution prediction. The data looks like this:

```
                     pollution  dew  temp   press wnd_dir  wnd_spd  snow  rain
date
2010-01-02 00:00:00      129.0  -16  -4.0  1020.0      SE     1.79     0     0
2010-01-02 01:00:00      148.0  -15  -4.0  1020.0      SE     2.68     0     0
2010-01-02 02:00:00      159.0  -11  -5.0  1021.0      SE     3.57     0     0
2010-01-02 03:00:00      181.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     5.36     1     0
2010-01-02 04:00:00      138.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     6.25     2     0
```

So I would really like to transform this example for solving my problem. Let's say that we have 3 cities where we need to predict air pollution and solve the problem. How the data for LSTM will be look like? Do we need to use tensors for this or we just need to add additional column like `cityID` and then do like that:

```
date                   cityID
2010-01-02 00:00:00      1 
2010-01-02 01:00:00      1
2010-01-02 02:00:00      1
2010-01-02 03:00:00      1
2010-01-02 04:00:00      1
2010-01-02 00:00:00      2 
2010-01-02 01:00:00      2
2010-01-02 02:00:00      2
2010-01-02 03:00:00      2
2010-01-02 04:00:00      2
2010-01-02 00:00:00      3 
2010-01-02 01:00:00      3
2010-01-02 02:00:00      3
2010-01-02 03:00:00      3
2010-01-02 04:00:00      3
```

Comment: If you think the prediction function will be very difficult across cities, you could separate your data in three datasets, one for each city. Then, train a specific classifier for each one. Does it makes sense?

Comment: If I would have 50 cities for example?

Comment: Think about your cities. Is the source of the pollution the same? Weather patterns the same? Same time zones (in the same that the time-wise pattern is the same)? Located in roughly the same geographical situation, similar latitude? If the cities are significantly different, it is going to impact your accuracy because your implicitly assuming in your data that they are equal. In that case, it is better to separate data and networks. Since this is hard to quantify, it is best to try both and see which one gives better results.

Comment: For splitting it is understandable for me and I can do separate models. My question was different-can you please show me the steps how can I do it at once in one model based on my example. Is that feasible for you?